# Creating Postgres table on AWS RDS using CSV file

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I'm having this issue with creating a table on my postgres DB on AWS RDS by importing the raw csv data. Here's the few steps that I already did.

1. CSV file has been uploaded on my S3 bucket
2. Followed AWS's tutorial to give RDS permission to import data from S3
3. Created an empty table on postgres
4. Tried using pgAdmin's 'import' feature to import the local csv file into the table, but it kept giving me the error.

So I'm using this query below to import the data into the table:

```
SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
    'public.bayarea_property_data',
    '',
    '(FORMAT CSV, HEADER true)',
    'cottage-prop-data',
    'clean_ta_file_edit.csv',
    'us-west-1'
);
```

However, I keep getting this message:

```
ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY bayarea_property_data, line 2: ",2009.0,2009.0,0.0,,0,2019,13061.0,,0,0.0,0.0,,2019,0.0,6767.0,576040,172810,403230,70,1,,1.0,,6081,..."
SQL statement "copy public.bayarea_property_data  from '/rdsdbdata/extensions/aws_s3/amazon-s3-fifo-6261-20200819T083314Z-0' with (FORMAT CSV, HEADER true)"
SQL state: 22P04
```

Anyone can help me with this? I'm an AWS noob, so have been struggling over the past few days. Thanks!

Comment: Open the csv file in a spreadsheet program.  Based on the message, the file has some rows with more fields than there are columns in your database table.  Verify that your table has the right number of columns to accept all rows from the file.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Mike. Just to clarity, does that mean I have to already have all those columns in my db table? Again, the table is totally empty, and I just didn't think it's reasonable to add +300 columns that match the columns in CSV. Any other workaround for this?

Comment: The table must have a column for each field in the file.  I recommend using text processing tools like `cut` (save it as tab-delimited first) or write a script to pick out the columns that you want.

Comment: It is not only reasonable it is what [table_import_from_s3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html#USER_PostgreSQL.S3Import.FileFormats) requires. Either you specify a subset of the fields that match the columns in the table or you create a table that has all the columns.

Comment: @ Mike Organek, @YongjoonKim. Some tools that help with ```CSV``` side of things: [csvkit-csvcut](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvcut.html), [querycsv](https://pythonhosted.org/querycsv/).